# Automatically check for updates on web application

Tags: java, performance, web-applications, primefaces, notifications

I'm doing a web application where users has interactions and notifications about these interactions or about system administrator changes, etc.

My server is implemented on Java and for GUI I'm using JSF (PrimeFaces libraries).

My puntual doubt is:
What is the best way that the client be always asking the server to get new notifications? I mean, something like here in StackExchange or like in Facebook, that if I'm writting a question or updating a status or doing anything else, I dont need to click notifications button every time that I want to know my new notifications, my client app simply is always checking for these updates (by a method I dont know).

The way I think this could be done is by having a function (on a thread or somethig like it) of infinitely duration that ask every minute to the server these notifications by calling the server notifications service (for example) and showing them to the user. The obvious problem is that I think this is not an optimized method, and there has to be a better way to doit.

It would be also great if someone know the method Facebook (StackExchange, Twitter or any system that handles user notifications) uses and make a try to explain it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What u are describing is ajax or http long pooling. This is resource consuming. Most probably a trully async implementation is far better. You are looking at websockets

Comment: Sonds great, this seems to be what I need, I havent heared about this. I'm going to read about it. Thanks dude.